# How can I select only checked inputs that are visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple objects like below

```
<input type="checkbox" class="to-labelauty-icon labelauty" 
  name="inputLableautyNoLabeledCheckbox" data-plugin="labelauty" 
  data-label="false" id="labelauty-0001" value="tc_Login">
```

I'm using the code below to get all the checked objects, which give me all the elements which are checked regardless of their visible/hidden status.

```
$('input[class="to-labelauty-icon labelauty"]:checked')
```

How can I get only the visible and checked elements?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ ?

Comment: Is there any reason to use an attribute selector here?

Comment: @isherwood Theoretically, it would match only those inputs with those two classes, in that order, in the HTML. Why that would be helpful is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and you can also combine the classes using `dot` selector notation

```
$('input.to-labelauty-icon.labelauty:visible:checked')
```

Comment: this gives me `jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
length: 0
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init [document]
__proto__: Object(0)` in chrome console, I'm not getting the checked and visible elements using this

Comment: That is a log of the jquery object. You need to do something with that object. Provide a [mcve] and explantion of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: `$('input[class="to-labelauty-icon labelauty"]:checked:hidden')` if I use this, then I get all the elements even the visible elements included. why is it that visible selector not working for this

Comment: Again...provide a full example ...as in jsfiddle, codepen, plunker etc